# How to count the number of variables in a first-order logic formula?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

There are actually two kinds of variables in a logic formula, i.e., free variable and bound variable. And I want to know that in a $k$-variable logic formula, is the $k$ the number of free or bound variables, or the sum of two kinds of variables?

The definition of $k$-variable logic comes from this paper [Logarithmic Weisfeiler-Leman Identifies All Planar Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.16218).

Comment: I think the *free* ones.

Comment: The linked paper is in an area of model theory where "$k$-variable" usually means that one counts all the variables, both free and bound, and requires the total number to be at most $k$. It is also usual to allow re-use of variables, so the same variable could be bound at several places in a formula, and that would count as only one variable. (This corresponds to $k$-pebble Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games where pebbles can not only be placed on elements of the models but can also be moved to other elements.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested above, I'm promoting my comment to an answer:

The linked paper is in an area of model theory where "$k$-variable" usually means that one counts all the variables, both free and bound, and requires the total number to be at most $k$. It is also usual to allow re-use of variables, so the same variable could be bound at several places in a formula, and that would count as only one variable. (This corresponds to $k$-pebble Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games where pebbles can not only be placed on elements of the models but can also be moved to other elements.)